# How to write prolog rule?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a prolog rule which will generate all the people in a social network using S number degrees of separation.

This is the rule that i have made but it is only printing empty lists. Can somebody please help me into helping me understand why this is happening and me where i am going wrong?:

```
socialN(_,N):- N<1,!.
socialN(_,N,_,_):- N<1,!.
socialN(P1,Separation,S1,S):-
    (message(P1,P2,_); message(P2,P1,_)),
    D is Separation-1,
    \+(member(P2,S1)),
    append(P2,S1,S2),socialN(P1,D,S2,S),!.
socialN(P2,Separation,S,S).
```

These are the facts:

```
message(allan, steve, 2013-09-03).
message(nayna, jane, 2013-09-03).
message(steve, jane, 2013-09-04).
message(steve, allan, 2013-09-04).
message(mark, martin, 2013-09-04).
message(martin, steve, 2013-09-04).
message(allan, martin, 2013-09-05).
```

E.g. Mark’s network includes just Martin for 1 degree of separation; it includes Martin, Steve and Allan for 2 degrees of separation; and Martin, Steve, Allan and Jane for 3.

Comment: Wnat's the meaning or purpose of the `socialN/2` predicate?

Comment: It stands for social Network...ive just labelled it socialN

Comment: I mean `socialN/2` versus `socialN/4`. You have one which has 2 parameters, and the others have 4.

Comment: Ive tried to link the one with two parameters to the one with four to show the user that they cannot insert 0 or less degrees of separation- They an only insert 1 or more degrees of separation. Then i have tried to link the one with four to the main rule to show what we are trying to find out/ get the result of

Comment: `append(P2,...)` will always fail since `P2` is not a list. Also, watch for your `D` parameter. Note that if you want to pre-pend one element `P2` to a list `S1`, you can just say `[P2|S1]` and don't need `append`. Your predicate subtracts one, but what should happen when it goes to zero?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ive tried to use recursion for that section so that there are no duplicates.

Comment: What would i have instead of append(P2...)? In this rule i am trying to find out the people they have interacted with in their S degrees of separation- so thats why i have included P2?.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using `append` and `member`, so I suppose you are trying to build up a list of people. I was a bit surprised that you were not using `findall`. Like this:

```
allDirectLinks(P1, L) :- findall(P2, directlyLinked(P1, P2), L).

directlyLinked(P1, P1).
directlyLinked(P1, P2) :- message(P1, P2, _).
directlyLinked(P1, P2) :- message(P2, P1, _).
```

From there, you can write a recursive function to find the indirect links:

```
socialN(0, P, [P]) :- !.
socialN(N, P1, L3) :-
    N>0, !,
    N1 is N-1,
    socialN(N1, P1, L1)
    maplist(allDirectLinks, L1, L2),
    append(L2, L3).
```

For example, this yields in Y a list of people separated 2 steps or less from Mark:

```
socialN(2, mark, X), list_to_set(X, Y).
```

Please note, Mark himself is included in the resulting list (being a 'level 0' link); I suppose it cannot be too hard to filter that out afterwards.

I hope this makes sense; I am a bit rusty, haven't done any Prolog in 25 years.

**EDIT:** explanation of the rules I defined:

- **directlyLinked**: true if there is a message between two persons (regardless of the direction of the message)
- **allDirectLinks**: accumulates into list *L* all persons directly linked to a given person *P1*; just read the manual about *findall*
- **socialN**: builds up a list of people connected to a given person (*P*) at a distance less than or equal to a given distance (*N*)

  - **socialN(0, ...)**: at distance 0, every person is linked to himself
  - **socialN(N, ...)**: makes a recursive call to get a list of connections at distance *N-1*, then uses *maplist* to apply *allDirectLinks* to every connection found, and finally uses *append* to concatenate the results together.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. Can you please explain how the code works and what i am supposed to write in the query? Thank you once again

Comment: When written in a query the answers are shown like this:           [1] 7 ?- socialN(2,mark,X),list_to_set(X,Y).
X = [mark, martin, martin, steve, mark, allan],
Y = [mark, martin, steve, allan].

Can you please explain what the X means because i only need the answers written for Y. And also can you please explain how the code works in detail so that i can understand it better- that would be really nice of you. Thank you so much once again

Comment: I can tell this is way over your head. What you need at this time is a Prolog training course. And just in case you are taking one already: I really should not be doing your homework.

Comment: @user3183631: Oh alright; please see the edit in my answer above.